# IOS DidReceiveRemoteNotification Issue

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am doing project in that push notification is the one of the key feature.It is working fine when i am in the app,I received notification and handle that notification.

But the issue is when my app is inactive state or else  remove the instance of the app.In this scenario i have received the notification didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not called, and i didn't handle the push notification.

Answer (score 2):

When the App is inactive and a push notification comes through the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method gets called when the app is resumed and the launchOptions dictionary has the push notification, which you can get with

```
launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
```

then you can process it as normal.

Comment: thank you for your reply.I agree that , but did n't worked for me